# How do I specify the field in an object to update with a string or some other pointer c#

Tags: user-interface, polymorphism

I'm just learning visual c# in visual studio

Ok, so I have a ton of data fields in a form, and then I want to write the handlers to all call one main method, update, which then updates a resultsEntry object, which encapsulates a bunch of uint variables with various names.

How do I write an update method to put in either the results object, or the update method that will take the name of the variable in resultsEntry as a string, and the integer to update it with, and then update that field.

Basically, I need to do a

```
resultsEntry.(inStringHere) = inValueHere;
```

where resultsEntry is the object being updated, the inStringHere specifies the field to be updated, and the inValueHere represents the integer value to assign to it.

Thanks!
Sam French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two challenges,

1. Setting a field/property in class using a string (the focus of your question). This will be accomplished using reflection.
2. Converting values to the type in your class (this may not be a problem for you, you may have 'typed' values. I have an ugly solution because this is not the main focus of your question.

Setting a property by name (see comments preceded with '**'):

```
    static class Program
    {
    // A 'ResultEntry' type
    public class ResultEntry
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // some tuples Field1 = Property Name; Field2 = Raw Value (string)  
        List<Tuple<string, string>> rawEntries = new List<Tuple<string, string>>() { 
            new Tuple<string,string>("ID", "1")
            , new Tuple<string, string>("FirstName", "George") 
            , new Tuple<string, string>("LastName", "Washington")
        };

        ResultEntry resultEntry = new ResultEntry();

        // ** Get MemberInfo's for your ResultEntry. Do this once, not for each instance of ResultEntry!
        MemberInfo[] members = resultEntry.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Iterate over input
        foreach (var raw in rawEntries)
        {
            // find a MemberInfo (PropertyInfo) that matches your input 'PropertyName'
            MemberInfo member = members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property && m.Name == raw.Item1);
            if (member != null)
            {
                // if you input is typed you will not have to deal with 
                //   conversion of the string to the actual type of the property
                object val = raw.Item2.MyConverter(((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType);

                // ** set the value in 'ResultEntry'
                ((PropertyInfo)member).SetValue(resultEntry, val, null);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result Entry: ID = {0}, FirstName = {1}, LastName = {2}", resultEntry.ID, resultEntry.FirstName, resultEntry.LastName));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you need to deal with converting raw string input to type (e.g. string to int), then is just one strategy...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static object MyConverter(this string rawValue, Type convertToMe)
    {
        // ugly, there are other strategies
        object val;
        if (convertToMe == typeof(Int32))
            val = Convert.ToInt32(rawValue);
        // ... add other type conversions
        else
            val = rawValue;

        return val;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.